# how to display bigger resolution images in android?

Tags: android

referring  to the code example of mine

[android Remote image Getting problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997703/android-remote-image-getting-problem)

how can i accommodate bigger resolution images in android.

when i try to display bigger resolution image from internet it give me null bitmap.

any one guide me whats the solution?

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would like to suggest a rather simple way to display high resolution images i.e. if u just want to display them n not store them.

there are some nice answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278625/android-imageview-scrolling-to-display-full-high-quality-image). Hope it helps to achieve wat u expect...